# Remove all characters after first non-numeric character using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, sed, bash-scripting, awk

### TL;DR:

How can I create an expression using either `sed` or `awk` that will remove *all* characters after (and including) the first character that is *not* either numeric (i.e. `[0-9]`) or a period (`.`). I've found previous SE posts that describe how to remove non-numeric characters and retain *all* numeric characters (for [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057065/remove-all-non-numeric-characters-from-text-files)), but in my case I may want to remove some numeric characters depending on where they occur.

### Use case:

I'm writing a shell script to check the version numbers of multiple packages against a list of minimum requirements. I have a function to do this but the version numbers cannot contain characters besides digits and periods.

Sometimes, however, the version number contains non-numeric characters I would need to remove. For example, on my machine, `bash --version` yields

```
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

I can easily isolate the `5.0.3(1)-release` portion using `head` and `cut`, but I would like trim it down to `5.0.3`. This is easy enough to do in this specific example, but I am looking for a general expression that will do this in a variety of different cases.

```
4.6.0.225-235f --> 4.5.0.225
5.28.1'; --> 5.28.1
4.19.0-9-cloud-amd64 --> 4.19.0-9
```

etc

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/[^0123456789.].*//'
```

`[0123456789.]` would match a digit or a period. `^` inside `[]` negates the whole thing, so `[^0123456789.]` in our command matches "the first character that is not either numeric or a period". Then `.*` matches "all characters after" (in the line). The command replaces a matching fragment with an empty string.

I'm not using `[0-9]` because it depends on the locale. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230/108618) to [**Difference between `[0-9]`, `[[:digit:]]` and `\d`**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414226/108618)
. But if you know you really want `[0-9]` then the command will be

```
sed 's/[^0-9.].*//'
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much not just for the reply but for the clear explanation! I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.